# Rosmake UWSim error - 1 package failed

Tags: ros, rosmake, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, Im trying to install UWSim again. I also followed all tutorials but when I run rosmake UWSim after some time it says:

```
    [ rosmake ] Last 40 linesderwater_sensor_msgs: 15... [ 1 Active 43/49 Complete ]
and after that line it is all mess:

{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/viki/underwater_simulation/underwater_sensor_msgs/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/viki/underwater_simulation/underwater_sensor_msgs/build'
  [  0%] Built target rosbuild_premsgsrvgen
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/viki/underwater_simulation/underwater_sensor_msgs/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/viki/underwater_simulation/underwater_sensor_msgs/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/viki/underwater_simulation/underwater_sensor_msgs/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/viki/underwater_simulation/underwater_sensor_msgs/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/viki/underwater_simulation/underwater_sensor_msgs/build'
  [ 20%] [ 80%] [100%] Built target ROSBUILD_genmsg_py
  Generating ../msg_gen/cpp/include/underwater_sensor_msgs/DVL.h
  Generating ../msg_gen/cpp/include/underwater_sensor_msgs/Pressure.h
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/ros/groovy/share/roscpp/rosbuild/scripts/genmsg_cpp.py", line 44, in <module>
      msg_gen.generate_messages(sys.argv)
    File "/opt/ros/groovy/share/roscpp/rosbuild/scripts/msg_gen.py", line 740, in generate_messages
        File "/opt/ros/groovy/share/roscpp/rosbuild/scripts/genmsg_cpp.py", line 44, in <module>
      generate(arg)
    File "/opt/ros/groovy/share/roscpp/rosbuild/scripts/msg_gen.py", line 710, in generate
      msg_gen.generate_messages(sys.argv)
    File "/opt/ros/groovy/share/roscpp/rosbuild/scripts/msg_gen.py", line 740, in generate_messages
      write_traits(s, spec, cpp_prefix, rospack=rospack)
    File "/opt/ros/groovy/share/roscpp/rosbuild/scripts/msg_gen.py", line 588, in write_traits
      generate(arg)
    File "/opt/ros/groovy/share/roscpp/rosbuild/scripts/msg_gen.py", line 710, in generate
      gendeps_dict = roslib.gentools.get_dependencies(spec, spec.package, compute_files=False, rospack=rospack)
  TypeError: get_dependencies() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rospack'write_traits(s, spec, cpp_prefix, rospack=rospack)
  
    File "/opt/ros/groovy/share/roscpp/rosbuild/scripts/msg_gen.py", line 588, in write_traits
      gendeps_dict = roslib.gentools.get_dependencies(spec, spec.package, compute_files=False, rospack=rospack)
  TypeError: get_dependencies() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rospack'
  make[3]: *** [../msg_gen/cpp/include/underwater_sensor_msgs/Pressure.h] Error 1
  make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  make[3]: *** [../msg_gen/cpp/include/underwater_sensor_msgs/DVL.h] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/viki/underwater_simulation/underwater_sensor_msgs/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ROSBUILD_genmsg_cpp.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/viki/underwater_simulation/underwater_sensor_msgs/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/viki/underwater_simulation/underwater_sensor_msgs/build'

    [ rosmake ] Output from build of package underwater_sensor_msgs written to:
    [ rosmake ]    /home/viki/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130403-160957/underwater_sensor_msgs/build_output.log
    [rosmake-0] Finished <<< underwater_sensor_msgs [FAIL] [ 15.35 seconds ]        
    [ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package underwater_sensor_msgs. 
    [ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
    [ rosmake ] Results:
    [ rosmake ] Built 44 packages with 1 failures. 
    [ rosmake ] Summary output to directory  
    [ rosmake ] /home/viki/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130403-160957
```

Can someone please help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59929/rosmake-uwsim-error---1-package-failed/) by [Marija-123](https://answers.ros.org/users/4397/marija-123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-04-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

had the same error. updating roslib solved it for me

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-roslib
```

---

Originally posted by [mthz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4610/mthz/) with karma: 66 on 2013-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2013-04-17**:
Got same error, this answer resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just got the same error by installing the velodyne trunk & updating my complete ROS :/

File "/opt/ros/groovy/share/roscpp/rosbuild/scripts/msg_gen.py", line 588, in write_traits
gendeps_dict = roslib.gentools.get_dependencies(spec, spec.package, compute_files=False, rospack=rospack)
TypeError: get_dependencies() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rospack'

Waiting for an answer with you ...

---

Originally posted by [Dexter111](https://answers.ros.org/users/4297/dexter111/) with karma: 86 on 2013-04-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-04-17**:
Not an answer. Please use the commenting function.